# Creating objects of R S4 classes in Rcpp?

Tags: r, rcpp

There is an S4 R class whose object I need to create in Rcpp. Is it possible to do this, and if yes, how?

Comment: What kind of R class? S3? S4? R6? Atomic?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Sure. Here is something taken from the S4 unit tests in the Rcpp package.

We first create a `track` class in R.  We then create a minimal function creating an `S4` object by supplying a string to the constructor and return it:

```
R> setClass("track", representation(x="numeric", y="numeric"))
R> cppFunction('SEXP trythis(std::string txt) { S4 foo(txt); return foo; }')
R> trythis("track")
An object of class "track"
Slot "x":
numeric(0)

Slot "y":
numeric(0)

R>
```

You can set slot values etc pp from C++.

Comment: Thanks for answering! Suppose I want to instantiate the object with some particular values, say x = 2, y = 3; how would it be done then?

Comment: I think you should be able to work that out given the available documentation such as the Rcpp vignettes _Introduction_, _FAQ_ and _Attributes_.  It really isn't that hard.